# If $W (\subset V)$ is a vector space, $W$ is a subspace of vector space $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra

True/False problem.

> $W$ is a subset of vector space $V$ and $W$ itself is also a vector space. Then is $W$ subspace of $V$?

My textbook says it's false.

Question 1 : Is the following (additional) condition enough to make statement true?

> Additive operation $+$ and scalar product operation $\cdot$ in $W(+,\cdot)$ works same as in $V(+',\cdot').$

I'm pretty sure that $W$ is subspace of $V$ if they share same operation (i.e. Field $F$). But How can I prove $(+,\cdot)=(+',\cdot')$ only with the following assumption? $$v+w=v+'w, \quad c\cdot v = c \cdot' v,\quad \quad v,w\in W$$

Question 2 : If one define being subspace up to isomorphism, anything 'bad' happens? By means of 'up to isomorphism',

> Let $V,W$ be vector spaces defined on a same Field $F(+,\cdot)$. Define $W$ is subspace of $V$ up to isomorphism if there is a subspace $W'$ of $V$ which is isomorphic to $W$

Comment: The additional condition says that the vector space operations on $W$ are the restriction of the vector space operations on $V$.

Comment: To your second question: it's frequently done in category theory, and 'subspace up to isomorphism' is called *subobject*, though the specific isomorphism $W\to W'$ (alternatively, the embedding $W\to V$) is part of the definition.